# Why do I get different QR codes from the same input with different QR generators?

Tags: barcode, qr-code, barcode-scanner

I generated 2 QR codes with 2 different generator tools but the same input data. They generated totally different looking QR codes. If I scan the codes I get the same data, so it seems OK, but I'm not sure about this phenomenon's cause.
Any idea?

**EDIT:**
Example:

[image: first]
[image: second]

The input data:
HTTP:/ /IQR.HU/Q/MP00AD483FEE6AC8E82B2B6D87C16526785BF6EA28731C943171C3907761E87BC8227C816202849A9FCF174B38016C26AA93ADD4883DD0943FAF7B5E38423E1792FA8EAB6DE5B5CD1BF42A0C2A8B5F73DD0E5E48F4E4FDF3E8356E5E3537D5C677D7377347075E3745B824A78EB808A6F8F6E96A8B710ADA30AD93DF7B96CE664CE5

Comment: It would be nice to see an example so maybe someone can tell you a little more

Comment: I edited and added an example - sorry for the size difference.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The encoding allows for a certain amount of variability in data representation.  The error correction level and/or the mask pattern are probably chosen differently by different implementations.  Customization may also play a role.  (There are [examples of QR codes which contain a pixelated image for PR reasons](https://hackaday.com/2011/08/11/how-to-put-your-logo-in-a-qr-code/) and still decode just fine.)

Comment: Wow, thanks! I haven't seen such QR code yet. I should have looked up the basics of QR code before asking.